# SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow Start a Task Process Return Fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer

I am designing my workflow in SharePoint 2013 Designer, a 2013 workflow, and using Start a Task Process. I need this because I need multiple people to be able to approve a single item.  My dilemma is after the approval I then need to email the approved item to another person with the approval comments.  I currently cannot figure out a way to retrieve the approved item comments to email the next person. This is so frustrating!  I cannot use assign a task because of the multiple people approving. let me know your suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, check if it’s feasible for your request: use SharePoint 2010 workflow platform.

Per my test, when I use the “Start Approval Process” action in SharePoint 2010 workflow, the workflow will email the approvers with the comments as below:

[image]

Comment: I cannot use sharepoint 2010 workflow. I need access to the list attachments which are not accessible in 2010, only through the rest api. I HATE sharepoint